# Bootstrap contact form sucess with ajax in the same page

Tags: ajax, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have this:

```
            <form role="form" method="post" action="validar.php" data-toggle="validator">
            <h2>¿Te interesa?<br>
            Nosotros te llamamos</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="Nombre">Nombre*</label><input data-error="Debes facilitarnos tu nombre" class="form-control" id="Nombre" name="Nombre" type="text" required />
                 <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="Empresa">Empresa</label><input class="form-control" id="Empresa" name="Empresa" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="Correo">Correo electrónico*</label><input data-error="Debes facilitarnos tu correo electrónico" class="form-control" id="Correo" name="Correo" type="email" required />
                 <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="Telefono">Teléfono</label><input class="form-control" id="Telefono" name="Telefono" type="tel">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="Horario">Qué día y hora prefieres</label><input class="form-control" id="Horario" name="Horario" type="text">
            </div>                 
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-image" name="send"><span style="position:relative;top: -20px;">Solicitar información</span></button>
            <div class="checkbox">
                 <label><input type="checkbox" required /><a target="_blank" href="http://www.trisquel.com/privacidad/">Acepto las condiciones</a></label>
            </div>
        </form>
```

validar.php recollect all the data (POST) and send and email.

I would like to add ajax/jquery code to show a Sucess Message (f.e: Thxs for all!) bellow the submit buttom when the user clicks in "submit" in the same page that the form and execute validar.php in the index page.

THXS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// this is the id of the form
$("#idForm").submit(function() {

    var url = "validar.php"; // the script where you handle the form input.

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: $("#idForm").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
           success: function(data)
           {
              $("message").text("Success Message");
           }
         });

    return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" id="idForm" method="post" action="validar.php" data-toggle="validator">
            <h2>¿Te interesa?<br>
            Nosotros te llamamos</h2>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="Nombre">Nombre*</label><input data-error="Debes facilitarnos tu nombre" class="form-control" id="Nombre" name="Nombre" type="text" required />
                 <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="Empresa">Empresa</label><input class="form-control" id="Empresa" name="Empresa" type="text">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="Correo">Correo electrónico*</label><input data-error="Debes facilitarnos tu correo electrónico" class="form-control" id="Correo" name="Correo" type="email" required />
                 <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="Telefono">Teléfono</label><input class="form-control" id="Telefono" name="Telefono" type="tel">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                 <label for="Horario">Qué día y hora prefieres</label><input class="form-control" id="Horario" name="Horario" type="text">
            </div>                 
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-image" name="send"><span style="position:relative;top: -20px;">Solicitar información</span></button>
            <div class="checkbox">
                 <label><input type="checkbox" required /><a target="_blank" href="http://www.trisquel.com/privacidad/">Acepto las condiciones</a></label>
            </div>
  
  <span id="message"></span>
        </form>
```

Comment: but <span id="message"></span> dont shows noting :( , he should shows "success message" when the user click on submit, the forms elements are serialized ¿whats wrong? , have i add something code to validar.php?

Comment: Is your php file being called ? What do you return back from the php file ? Is the Email going out ?

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery to serialize your form and post it.  Give your form an id so you can reference it(like myForm)

```
var serializedForm = $("#myForm").serialize();
```

Then post it with an Ajax call(read the jquery ajax docs).

In the success callback of the Ajax call you do the following.

```
$('#contactDiv').hide();
$('#successDiv').show();
```

So you'll need to create some divs around the form and another around the success message.